# Firebird results to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, firebird

I am trying to load the firebird results into asp.net gridview but it does not load anything. 
What am I doing wrong: All Im trying to do is to run a SP in firebrid, send a parameter and show the results in GridView.

```
public void BindGridview()
{
    try
    {
    transportFbConn.Open();

    if (transportFbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        transportFbConn.Open();
    }
    FbTransaction ft = transportFbConn.BeginTransaction();

    transportFbCommand = new FbCommand("EXECUTE PROCEDURE SPB_PNM_SO_HIST(@PNM)", transportFbConn, ft);

    transportFbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    transportFbCommand.Parameters.Add("@PNM", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.Integer, 9999999, "PNM_AUTO_KEY").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    transportFbCommand.Parameters[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Server.HtmlEncode(this.TextBox1.Text));

    FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter(transportFbCommand);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.ErrorLabel.Text = (ex.Message);
}

finally
{
    transportFbConn.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: An executable procedure only returns one row, are you sure your procedure isn't selectable (in which case you should use `SELECT ... FROM SPB_PNM_SO_HIST(@PNM)` instead)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark's reponce helped me and I used `Select * form Store Procedure (@parameter)` instead.